# Get value of parent element by child jq

Tags: jquery, json, bash, jq, jsonpath

Code:

```
{
  "endpointAgents": [
    {
      "agentId": "MyId",
      "agentName": "MYNAME",
      "location": {
        "locationName": "location"
      },
      "clients": [
        {
          "userProfile": {
            "userName": "Name"
          },
          "browserExtensions": [
            {
              "active": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "totalMemory": "16222 MB",
      "agentType": "enterprise"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to return the **agentId** value with the value **userName**.
I know how to do it with JSONPath

> ($.endpointAgents[?(@.clients.userName=~ 'a')].agentId)

, but don't know how with jq.

Comment: `jquery` is a javascript library and `jq` is a executable mostly for the shell. What is your App written with?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please post valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input JSON is

```json
{
  "endpointAgents": [
    {
      "agentId": "MyId",
      "agentName": "MYNAME",
      "location": {
        "locationName": "location"
      },
      "clients": [
        {
          "userProfile": {
            "userName": "Name"
          },
          "browserExtensions": [
            {
              "active": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "totalMemory": "16222 MB",
      "agentType": "enterprise"
    }
  ]
}
```

To get the `agentId` values from **all** items of the `endpointAgents` array where in the same object **at least one** object in the `clients` array has a `userProfile.userName` string value that **contains** a given substring, I'd go with

```sh
jq -r '
  .endpointAgents[]
  | select(.clients | map(.userProfile.userName | contains("a")) | any)
  | .agentId
'
```

```
MyId
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5_FLiPJAnD)

In order import the query string from outside jq, use the `--arg` parameter

```
jq -r --arg query "a" ' … contains($query) … '
```